# Qt executable naming

Tags: qt, ogre, ogre3d

I'm hoping this is an easy question. I have setup an Ogre3D project in QtCreator 2.6.1 using MSVC2010. I have to setup a custom build step and I noticed that the letter 'd' is appended to the name of the compiled .exe (e.g. OrgeProgramd.exe, CoolGamed.exe)

This is not critical, I was just wondering why this happens. Is it normal? The target in the .pro file is correct. I tried building with Release and I get the same thing. Any ideas?

Comment: The appended 'd' is meant to be for debug builds. You should have a look at your release makefile.

Answer (score 1):

Look through your pro/pri files and find the line, similar to this: `TARGET = $$join(TARGET,,,d)`. If you do - that would be the reason.